# How to use Activity Feed to show latest action on fan page of application?

Tags: facebook

I can't figure it out. I am trying paste link in that wizard (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity) to wall of fan page or direct link to fan page of my application and it doesnt work. Shows some random stuff... Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The activity feed is meant to show web site domain activity on a web page. You have to paste the code onto an HTML file. For example, this shows an activity feed for activity on facebook.com and developers.facebook.com:

```
<html> 
<body> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script> 

<fb:activity site="facebook.com, developers.facebook.com" width="300" height="500" header="true" font="" border_color="" recommendations="false"></fb:activity> 

</body> 
</html>
```